# not able to access WSDL end point in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, soap

I have created a Spring Boot SOAP web service : that accepts two numbers and display addition of them.

I am not able to access WSDL endpoint: Error is Standardized Whitelabel page.

Code and pom.xml file is below:

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.operations</groupId>
  <artifactId>operations-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>operations-service</name>
  <description>SOAP Web Services with Spring Boot</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
          <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**EndPoint Java Class**:

```
package com.example.operations.endpoint;

import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import com.example.operations.OperationsRequest;
import com.example.operations.OperationsResponse;

@Endpoint
public class OperationsEndPoint
{
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://example.com/operations", localPart = "OperationsRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public OperationsResponse performOperations(OperationsRequest request)
    {
        OperationsResponse response = new OperationsResponse();
        int num1 = request.getNumber1();
        int num2 = request.getNumber2();
        response.setNumber1(num1);
        response.setNumber2(num2);
        response.setResult(num1 + num2);
        response.setOperationtype("add");

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Config Java Class:**

```
package com.example.operations.config;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;


@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
    messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(messageDispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");
  } 

  @Bean(name = "operations")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema) {
  DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
  definition.setPortTypeName("OperationsPort");
  definition.setTargetNamespace("http://example.com/operations");
  definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
  definition.setSchema(schema);
  return definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema schema() {
  return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("operations.xsd"));
}
}
```

Let me know where I am making mistakes. I am executing the application using this command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: what is the URL you try to access ? is there any error in startup log ?

Comment: No error in startup log, I am accessing WSDL through this URL : http://localhost:8080/ws/operations.wsdl